# Question on Proof of Theorem 2.20 in Walter Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working through the proof of Theorem 2.20 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis and am getting stuck.  The statement of the theorem is as follows:
[image]

He starts the proof with defining a positive linear functional:
[image]

He defines $P_n$ earlier in the text as well as some other relevant terms as:

[image]

I understand what Rudin is doing with uniform continuity, but I don't understand how property (c) of the collection $\Omega_n$ is used to show that $\land_N g = \land_n g$.  Any elaboration on this point would be appreciated.

Comment: `$\Lambda$` creates $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the property (c), for $n>N$, the set $P_{n}$ has exactly $2^{(n-N)k}$ points in $Q\in\Omega_{N}$. On the other hand, from (a) of 2.19 we know for each $x\in P_{n}$, there is only one $Q\in\Omega_{N}$ such that $x\in Q$. Now $g$ is constant on each $Q$ belonging to $\Omega_{N}$, thus we have$$\begin{aligned}\Lambda_{n}g&=2^{-nk}\sum_{x\in P_{n}}g(x)=2^{-nk}\sum_{Q\in\Omega_{N}}\sum_{x\in P_{n}\cap Q}g(x)\\
&=2^{-nk}\sum_{Q\in\Omega_{N}}2^{(n-N)k}\cdot g|_{Q}=2^{-Nk}\sum_{x\in P_{N}}g(x)\\
&=\Lambda_{N}g.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I'm still a little confused though.  How does the fact that $P_n$ has $2^{(n-N)k}$ points in $Q \epsilon \Omega_N$ give you the middle equality?

Comment: @TeaDrinker7 I have edited it.

Comment: Okay, I think I follow everything now.  Thanks so much for your explanation.